# How to change the first charcater of every new line in a file using python

Tags: python

I have a file which looks like this:

```
1 1:10 2:10 3:40
2 1:30 3:40 4:20
1 1:20 4:40 3:30
```

I would like to change the first character, say 1 or 2 or 1 to -1, 1 and -1 respectively.

I had written the following python code

```
with open('filename') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


for line in lines:
    if line[0] == '1':  
        print(line)

        line = line.split();
        line[0] = "-1"
        line = "".join(line)

    else:
        line = line.split("");
        line[0] = "1"
```

The space character is removed the by split and I don't think   can write this into an output file. my output should ultimately look like this

```
-1 1:10 2:10 3:40
 1 1:30 3:40 4:20
-1 1:20 4:40 3:30
```

The code to write the modified file is

```
with open('changed_file', 'w') as fout:
    for line in lines:
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: _"I don't think can write this into an output file."_ Why not? What happened when you tried?

Comment: `line = "".join(line)` - how about `line = " ".join(line)`

Comment: the space in the original file is not getting saved when i use split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads in all of the lines, and changes the lines that start with `1` or `2` as you said, then proceeds to rewrite the file with the edited lines.

```
with open('<file_name>', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0) # moves cursor back to the beginning of the file
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('1'): line = '-1' + line[1::]
        elif line.startswith('2'): line = '1' + line[1::]
        f.write(line)
```

New file contents:

```
-1 1:10 2:10 3:40
1 1:30 3:40 4:20
-1 1:20 4:40 3:30
```

Answer (score 3):

have you consider something like this?

```
line = "1 1:10 2:10 3:40"
map = {'1': '-1', '2': '1'}
print map[line[0]] + line[1:-1]
#-1 1:10 2:10 3:4
```

You can also set a default value to the `map` dict.

Best,
Alvaro.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that after changing your lines, you're joining them by an empty space, when it should be joined with an interval.

```
for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    split_line = line.split()

    if split_line[0] == '1':
        split_line[0] = "-1"
    else:
        split_line[0] = "1"

    lines[idx] = " ".join(split_line)
```

Comment: And `split_line[0] = " 1"`?

Comment: I am unable to write this out after changing. it is still writing the original file.I updated the code

Comment: That's because it wasn't changing the original list, I updated the code too, try now.

Comment: I tried to head the file but i think the lines are getting merged into each other.

Comment: The problem is that you are not adding a new line to the end of each line.


Use `fout.writelines(lines)` instead of the for loop altogether. That should write every line in your `lines` list as a new line.

Or, use `fout.write(line + '\n')`. This will add a new-line to the string you're writing.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('output', 'w') as output:
    for line in lines:
        if line[0] == '1': 
            line = "-1" + line[1:] 
        else:
            line = "1" + line[1:]
        print(line, file=output, end="")
```